# ternary operators with multiple statements

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

/*
 * Use a series of ternary operator to set the category to one of the following:
 *   - "herbivore" if an animal eats plants
 *   - "carnivore" if an animal eats animals
 *   - "omnivore" if an animal eats plants and animals
 *   - undefined if an animal doesn't eat plants or animals
 *
 * Notes
 *   - use the variables `eatsPlants` and `eatsAnimals` in your ternary expressions
 *   - `if` statements aren't allowed ;-)
 */

i used this code but it is not getting things right

```
  var eatsPlants = true;
var eatsAnimals = false;


var category = eatsPlants ? "herbivore" : "carnivore";
console.log(category);
var category = (eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : "undefined";
console.log(category);
```

any ideas to solve this problem

Comment: Hello and welcome! Remember that StackOverflow isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. It might be worth having a look at [this article][1] which has some tips on how to ask a great question that'll get you the answer you're looking for.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `undefined if an animal doesn't eat plants or animals` ... but you output undefined when an animal doesn't eat plants AND animals - you need to brush up on your boolean logic

Comment: also, it should be `undefined` for eats neither, not `"undefined"`

Comment: `eatsPlants ? (eatsAnimals ? "omnivore" : "herbivore") : (eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : undefined);`

Comment: doesn't eat plants or animals means that it is not eating them both, not one of them so i thought i should use && because using OR means that this animal may eat plants but not animals and in this case it will be herbivore and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

This will work -

`const category = (eatPlants && eatAnimals) ? 'omnivore' : eatAnimals ? 'carnivore' : eatPlants ? 'herbivore' : undefined;`

You need to chain one ternary's else part to another ternary and so on if you wish to draw out an if-else branch using ternary operator.

But I suggest, you sinply use if else branches **to maintain readability of your code**. Ternaries just make a little mess with multiple conditions.

This is how much clear it would have been in if-else logic.

```
let category = undefined;
if (eatPlants && eatAnimals)
     category = 'omnivore';
else if (eatPlants)
     category = 'herbivore';
else if (eatAnimals)
     category = 'carnivore';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem.

```
var eatsPlants = false;
var eatsAnimals = true;

var category = (eatsPlants) ? (eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : "herbivore" 
: eatsAnimals ? "carnivore" : undefined;

console.log(category);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var eatsPlants = false;
var eatsAnimals = false;

var category = (eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" :
               ( eatsPlants && ! eatsAnimals )? "herbivore" :
               (! eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "carnivore" : 
                "undefined" ;

console.log(category);
```